# Replace strings in a pandas column with a randomly generated code, and store the matchings in a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, random

I have a dataframe with a column containing strings that I am trying to replace with a randomly generated string, and keep a dictionary with the originals and the replacements.

Concretely, I have something like this:

```
  col1                       
0  Marie  
1  Marie  
2  Lucas 
3  Dog  
4  Table
5  Dog
```

And I want to replace those strings with a code. The format of the code is indifferent, but, for example, with à 6 characters only letters code, the output would look like this:

```
  col1                       
0  aadfre
1  aadfre
2  qwerty
3  lfkdjs
4  hgyeoy
5  lfkdjs
```

And I am trying to keep a dictionary of the matching, like this: `{'Marie': 'aadfre', 'Lucas': 'qwerty', 'Dog ': 'lfkdjs', 'Table': 'hgyeoy'}`

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks!!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Try using Python's string and randint module.

```
import pandas as pd
import string
from random import randint
```

Create Pandas Dataframe and our dictionary with real and encoded names

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['Marie','Marie','Lucas','Dog','Table','Dog'])

secret_names_dict = {name:''.join([string.ascii_lowercase[randint(0,25)] for char in range(6)]) for name in df[0].unique()}
```

I will break down steps in this dictionary comprehension.

Code below creates a list of 6 random lowercase characters

```
[string.ascii_lowercase[randint(0,25)] for char in range(6)]
```

and by using `''.join()` we will join them into string.

`.unique()` is Pandas method to extract unique values from column, we will use it to ensure same values are encoded in same way.

```
df[0].unique()
```

The rest is just dictionary comprehension, storing original values and encoded values.

This newly created dictionary can be easily used to rename values in column using Pandas .rename() function.

```
df.replace(secret_names_dict)
```

The result will be:

```
    0
    0   loixez
    1   loixez
    2   pavedm
    3   kigahn
    4   gybour
    5   kigahn
```

Hope that helps, I tried to keep it as simple as possible.